# retryWhen only calls service function only once when should be called multiple times within Jest

Tags: angular

I am trying to test the that the `getUser` http request is getting called 10 times after mocking the `getUser` function within the test by throwing an error:

```js
public getUser(userId: number, delayTime): Observable<any> {
    return this.myService.getUser(userId).pipe(
      map((result: any) => {
        if (result) {
          return { data: data };
        }
        throw new Error('Result is empty');
      }),
      retryWhen((error: Observable<any>) => {
        let retryCount = 0;
        return error.pipe(
          delay(delayTime),
          tap(() => {
            if (retryCount++ === 10) {
              throw error;
            }
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

However, when I try to test this within my test file:

```js
it('getUser throws error, getUser is called 10 times ', (done) => {
      // mock service
      myService.getUser = jest.fn(() => throwError('mock error'));
      getUser(23, 1).subscribe(() => {
        expect(myService.getUser).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        done();
      });
});
```

Even though the `retryWhen` block is hit 10 times, the `getUser` function is getting called only once according to the `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` function. If I replaced the `1` with a `10` I end up getting an error. I was wondering if there were any issues with the way the `retryWhen` block is setup or whether I set up the mock function improperly.

Answer (score 3):

`retryWhen()` will not call `myService.getUser(userId)` multiple times. `myService.getUser(userId)` simply returns one Observable, and `retryWhen()` operates on this one Observable.

The Observable returned by `retryWhen()` just tells the operator when to re-subscribe to the same source Observable, which gives the "retry" effect.